Where can I find the git repository with the manifest and related files used to create the Ubuntu release iso file?
This is the manifest file I'm talking about: https://releases.ubuntu.com/jammy/ubuntu-22.04.4-live-server-amd64.manifest
Where does it come from? Usually there is a git repository to maintain these kind of files that get used to create releases. Where is it?
